# Can you make conclusions about statistical significance from aggregate data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have aggregate data on complaints filed by two groups - group A and group B. I say 'aggregate' because I don't know how many complaints a particular individual filed. I just know that:

There are 100 people in group A. There were 30 complaints from group A.

There are 100 people in group B. There were 33 complaints from group B.

So, group B complained more (by 3 complaints). But can I make a conclusion about statistical significance of the difference in number of complaints? What test would I use?

Comment: Pro-Tip: The **unit of analysis** is always **part** of the inference you are making: for example, inferences about populations ≠ inferences about individuals and vice versa. Also: Welcome CV!

Comment: @Alexis, I don't understand how this relates to my question.

Comment: My take on @Alexis' comment can be explained by asking you a question in turn: would you view the groups as being "significantly different" if you were to learn that all the complaints in group B came from a single individual while the complaints in group A came from 30 individuals?

Comment: @whuber, thank you for trying to clarify this! I thought about this and my honest answer is 'I don't know.' So, let's say A is treated, and B is control. As I understand, there is no way to check if the treatment decreased the number of complaints ? Unless I assume, for example, 1 complaint/person; and then it's just a Chi-squared test?

Comment: That sounds basically right--although an equivalent test is the Binomial test of two proportions, as illustrated by BruceET's answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Comment:* Strictly speaking, in order to make a valid comparison using `prop.test` in R, you need to compare the number of *people* making complaints, not the *number of complaints.*
(One person making two or more complaints does not lead to multiple *independent* complaints.)

However, even if you had true binomial data, there would
still be no significant difference (5% level, 10% level, etc.) between 30 and and 33 people out of 100 making complaints:

```
prop.test(c(30,33), c(100,100))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(30, 33) out of c(100, 100)
X-squared = 0.092689, df = 1, p-value = 0.7608
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1686877  0.1086877
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
  0.30   0.33
```

The P-value is not below $0.05 = 5\%$ and the 95% confidence
interval contains $0.$

However, if you had similar proportions with 20 times
the sample sizes with true binomial data, you would (just barely) have a significant
result at the 5% level.

```
prop.test(c(600,660), c(2000,2000))$p.val
[1] 0.04461493
```

Comment: (-1) While your answer may help some, your method & results clearly do not fit the question due to your reliance on <=1 complaint per person.  Also you assume without sufficient basis that alpha = or should = .05.

Comment: @rolando2. Sorry, I don't understand your first sentence. As for the second: of course, 5% level is just intended as an example (matching the 95% CI in output).

Comment: The OP wrote, “I don't know how many complaints a particular individual filed.” So no way to know the number of people making complaints, and it’s not applicable to assume each person made at most one. S/he needs to know what test to use in the situation described.